# Issue when trying to store some data in a MongoDB data model

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I want to store some data in the following MongoDB model:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: 'User',
    },
    orderItems: [
      {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        qty: { type: Number, required: true },
        image: { type: String, required: true },
        price: { type: Number, required: true },
        product: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          required: true,
          ref: 'Product',
        },
      },
    ],
    shippingAdress: {
      address: { type: String, required: true },
      city: { type: String, required: true },
      postalCode: { type: String, required: true },
      state: { type: String, required: false },
      country: { type: String, required: true },
    },
    paymentMethod: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    paymentResult: {
      id: { type: String },
      status: { type: String },
      update_time: { type: String },
      email_address: { type: String },
    },
    taxPrice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.0,
    },
    shippingPrice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.0,
    },
    totalPrice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.0,
    },
    isPaid: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
    paidAt: {
      type: Date,
    },
    isDelivered: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
    deliveredAt: {
      type: Date,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);

export default Order;
```

But I am not able to post the following sample data to the database

```
{
 "orderItems": [
     {
       "product": "6060f2eb6bea3f2280c08a4c",
       "name": "Airpods Wireless Bluetooth Headphones",
       "image": "/images/airpods.jpg",
       "price": 89.99,
       "qty": 3
     }
   ],
   "user": "6060f2eb6bea3f2280c08a4b",
   "shippingAddress": {
     "address": "1st Avenue Main St",
     "city": "Boston",
     "postalCode": "02011",
     "country": "USA"
   },
   "paymentMethod": "Stripe",
   "itemsPrice": 269.97,
   "taxPrice": 40.50,
   "shippingPrice": 20.00,
   "totalPrice": 330.47
}
```

as I get the following error:
By the way I am trying to get that done through Postman

"Order validation failed: shippingAdress.country: Path `shippingAdress.country` is required., shippingAdress.postalCode: Path `shippingAdress.postalCode` is required., shippingAdress.city: Path `shippingAdress.city` is required., shippingAdress.address: Path `shippingAdress.address` is required."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your Model `shippingAdress`. It should be `shippingAddress`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, Nenad Milosavljevic